# IntelliJ Idea common (MacOs/Win) keymap

Tags: windows, macos, intellij-idea, keymapping

I'm employed company with strong it-security rules and I have to use their machines for the development (with Windows7 on board). For my pet projects I use my mac.

Intellij Idea 14 on both.

And it became ass-pain to switch my mind (and finger habits) between different keymaps. I can not use "MacOs 10.5+" on Windows because Meta-key is absent.

So my question (to people who have to live in same environment) – what is best approach to deal with this issue? What works for you?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is really a pain, tried various techniques. But I think even editing key maps it is not 100% similar between both. 
Would Like to know if you found a solution yet.

Comment: Yes, I found silver bullet to this problem - I changed company to one which give me a new mac without whole this security bullshit. )